# BASH - limit depth of directory loop

Tags: bash, unix

How can I loop through directories and restrict the depth to only 3 levels? My version of find does not have -maxdepth. I'd like to keep it to one line if possible.

e.g:  find /data -type d -print

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
shopt -s nullglob
for d in /data/*/ /data/*/*/ /data/*/*/*/
do
  echo "$d"
done
```

Comment: It doesn't do the `-type d` though; using `[ -d "$d" ] && echo "$d"` would, and you could drop setting `nullglob` then.

Comment: @user2719058: The terminating slash makes sure that it does, for the most part.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Ah, I stand corrected. Indeed, I didn't think about the slashes. What do you mean by "for the most part"? I can't think of cases where it doesn't work.

Comment: @user2719058: It will also include symlinks to directories.